# Recalculate normal of flat surface shader in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, cg

I'm making low poly water and I'm unsuccessfully trying to make the lighting work.

I have made a shader which sets a color to the model and moves its vertices along the z axis.

[This tutorial](http://diary.conewars.com/vertex-displacement-shader/) explains how to recalculate the normals in a shader. However it uses smooth shading which is explained very well in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMgjVJogIbc).

For my low poly water I need flat shading which, based on my understanding of the video, requires me to split each vertices in 3 separate vertices that have the same position but a different normal.

How can I achieve that?

Here is how it looks in Unity for now. Don't mind the ugliness of the waves as I just started writing this. The problem is the smoothed shadow inbetween the waves.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Shader "Ramble/LowPolyWater" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _Emission ("Emission", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _ScrollYSpeed("Scroll y speed", Float) = 0.1
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma surface surf Lambert fullforwardshadows vertex:vert addshadow

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        fixed4 _Color;
        fixed4 _Emission;
        float _ScrollYSpeed;

        float4 getNewVertPosition( float4 p ) {
            p.z += frac(sin( dot(p.xyz ,float3(12.9898,78.233,45.5432) )) * 43758.5453) * sin(_Time.y) * _ScrollYSpeed;;
            return p;
        }

        void vert (inout appdata_full v)
        {

            float4 bitangent = float4(cross( v.normal, v.tangent), 0);

            float4 position = getNewVertPosition( v.vertex );
            float4 positionAndTangent = getNewVertPosition( v.vertex + v.tangent * 0.01 );
            float4 positionAndBitangent = getNewVertPosition( v.vertex + bitangent * 0.01 );

            v.vertex.z = position.z;

            float4 newTangent = ( positionAndTangent - position ); // leaves just 'tangent'
            float4 newBitangent = ( positionAndBitangent - position ); // leaves just 'bitangent'

            float4 newNormal = float4(cross( newTangent, newBitangent), 0);
            v.normal = newNormal;
        }

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
            o.Albedo = (tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color).rgb;
            o.Emission = _Emission.rgb;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    Fallback "VertexLit"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a geometry shader for this - there is a great example on how these works, including how to do flat shading, here: https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/advanced-rendering/flat-and-wireframe-shading/

However, geometry shaders are very expensive, so i'd say the best option in this case is just to open the model in Blender, select it, and press "Flat" instead of "Smooth" as shading option in the left toolbar, and reexport it. This should give you split normals.